# Does not pick the right AppIcon when distributing Flutter app to App Store

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic, android-flavors

I have created multiple environments(Development, QA, Production) in my flutter app using flavors and it works fine. To differentiate each environments, I have created different AppIcons for each. When I run in iOS simulator it install with right AppIcon, but after distributing the App Store using 'Codemagic' it picks wrong icon 'AppIcon'(Default), it should be 'ProductionAppIcon'.

In Codemagic.yamal file:

```
     environment:
      vars:
        XCODE_WORKSPACE: "$FCI_BUILD_DIR/ios/Runner.xcworkspace"
        XCODE_SCHEME: "Runner"
  - app-store-connect fetch-signing-files "$BUNDLE_ID" --type IOS_APP_STORE --create
      - keychain add-certificates
      - xcode-project use-profiles

      - flutter build ipa -t lib/src/main_prod.dart — flavor Production --release
      - name: Build ipa for distribution
        script: xcode-project build-ipa --workspace "$XCODE_WORKSPACE" --scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME"
    
    artifacts:
      - build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
      - $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**/Build/**/*.dSYM
      - /tmp/xcodebuild_logs/*.log
      - '*.snap'
      - build/windows/**/*.msix
      - flutter_drive.log
```

Project folder structure is as follows:

[image]

Xcode configurations as follows:

[image]

Schemas are as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `xcode-project build-ipa` command because it re-builds ipa without flavor information.

Check this project out to see working demo of building Flutter flavors.

https://github.com/codemagic-ci-cd/codemagic-sample-projects/blob/main/flutter/flutter-flavors-demo-project/codemagic.yaml

And there is also extra whitespace before `flavor` in your command

```
flutter build ipa -t lib/src/main_prod.dart — flavor Production --release
```